# "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" only appears after exporting from codepen

Tags: javascript

I was using codepen to make a custom homepage
it worked until I exported it than...
Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.
and all my animations didn't work.
 heres my JS code

```
        window.onload = function(){
const left = document.querySelector(".left");
const right = document.querySelector(".right");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

left.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  container.classList.add("hover-left");
});

left.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  container.classList.remove("hover-left");
});

right.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  container.classList.add("hover-right");
});

right.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  container.classList.remove("hover-right");
});
}
```

and my HTML

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang"en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>...</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
     <div>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div class="split left">
        <h1>My Email</h1>
        <a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/" class="button">Go There</a>
      </div>
      <div class="split right">
        <h1>Google</h1>
        <a href="https://www.google.com.au/" class="button">Go There</a>
      </div>
    </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I hope someone can help me fix this error

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your javascript on page load. In `script.js` as the elements do not yet exist when it is currently running:

```
window.onload = function(){
   // rest of your code
}
```

Codepen does this automatically for you, which is why it worked there.

---

Edit: Your opening `<div>` element is also inside the `<head>` element and is missing the `class="container"` attribute.

Comment: still not working. now i get this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
    at HTMLDivElement.left.addEventListener (script.js:12)

Comment: @AnnoyingRain5 - there is no element in your html with the class `container`. You have a floating closing `div` element I suspect you've accidentally removed its opener.

Comment: I fixed the floating div but the the website didn't care it kept going on about the Cannot read property 'classList' of null at HTMLDivElement.left.addEventListener (script.js:12)

Comment: @AnnoyingRain5 well your variable `container` is definitely `null` then. Which means there is still no element with the class `container`. Happy to help you sort this problem but need to see what your html looks like now youve fixed it

Comment: @AnnoyingRain5 - you now have a `<div>` inside the `<head>` and it *still* doesnt have the class `container`